# How to display a list of user inputs, using html5 local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage, local

I am creating my first html5 web app, which records the users weight progress. At the moment i have a simple form which prints the input underneath. I want it to be saved in the local storage, and i would also like to be able to add more inputs and display them in a table. Can someone help me with this please? Im a bit of a novice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home Fitness</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

<script>
    function display(form){
        form.o_weight.value = form.weight.value;
    return false;
    }
    </script>


    </head>

    <body>
<header>
    <h1>Weight Tracker</h1>
</header>

    <article>
<h2>Weight Input</h2>
    <p>Please enter your current weight below and submit.</p>
    </article>

<form name="input" action="" method="get" onsubmit="return display(this);">

    <section>

    <p>Weight:</p><input type="text" name="weight">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </section>

    <section>       
      <table>

    <th>Weight</th>

    <tr>
    <td><output name="o_weight" style="width:100px; height:20px"></output></td>
     </tr>
      </table>

    </section>

    </form>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <footer>

        </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function display(form){
    //get all form elements
    var elements = form.elements;
    //loop through the elements
    for(var i = 0; i< elements.length; i++){
        //store every item individually
        localStorage.setItem(elements[i].name, elements[i].value);
    }
}
```

retrieve a value with:

```
var weigth = localStorage.getItem('weight');//input with name "weigth"
```

Comment: hey, i feel like what your saying is correct, however forgive more being a bit of a noob! but cold you explain what this code is doing and how i can incorporate it in to my simple form. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @user2336624 Try to replace the `display` function with the one I wrote above. After that check the console window and check if the items are correctly stored. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Store weight along with other form elements into in localStorage as stringified Object
with key as current Date.

Step 1:Getting form elements

```
function getFormElementValues("formName"){
 //get hold of form and get the corresponding values into Object
}
```

Above function should return Object with form element labels along with their values.

```
e.g 
 {
  weight: 100,
  unit : "KG",
  breadsYouAte:3
}
```

Step 2:Put current time as key and Put into Object

```
function addCurrentTime(formObject){
  var d = new Date();
  var dString = d.getTime(); 
  return {dString : formObject}
}
```

Step 3: Store to localStorage

```
function StoreObject(objectWithTime){
  var formString = JSON.stringify(objectWithTime);
  if(localStorage['formName']){
    //this will get executed only for first time
    localStorage['formName'] = [formString];
  }else{
    var arrayString = JSON.parse(localStorage['formName']);
    arrayString.push(formString);
  }
}
```

Step 4: execute the helper functions created on 3 steps,

```
var form = getFormElementValues("formName")
var formTimeObject = addCurrentTime(form)
var store = storeObject(formTimeObject)
```